# yii2 insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i am trying to insert data into mysql database in yii but i want to be able to access each of the input in the controller . 
  so i can place them in a foreach because they all have the same name but the problem is any time 
  i try to access the in put name i get this error "Undefined index: Topic[topic]"... like the input does not exist in the view

this is my controller

```
  public function actionCompose()
    {
     $topic= new Topic();  
     $topic->topic_id = Yii::$app->request->post('Topic','[topic]'); 

    foreach ($_POST["Topic[topic]"] as $key => $top) {
      $top=> $topic;
    }
        if ($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            $topic->load($topic);
        $topic->save();
        return $this->refresh();
           }
       return $this->render('compose');
       }
```

this is my view

```
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use common\models\Comment;
use common\models\Users;
use common\models\Candidate;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic"> 
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

when i use it like this below it inserts only the last data . and i understand why but i need to insert all 3 inputs. any other way to do it.

```
  public function actionCompose()
    {
     $topic= new Topic();  

        if ($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            $topic->load($_POST);
        $topic->save();
        return $this->refresh();
           }
       return $this->render('compose');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with multiple models of the same type is covered in official documentation in article [Collecting tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html).

Here are some important parts.

Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Setting;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $settings = Setting::find()->indexBy('id')->all();

        if (Model::loadMultiple($settings, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($settings)) {
            foreach ($settings as $setting) {
                $setting->save(false);
            }
            return $this->redirect('index');
        }

        return $this->render('update', ['settings' => $settings]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin();

foreach ($settings as $index => $setting) {
    echo $form->field($setting, "[$index]value")->label($setting->name);
}

ActiveForm::end();
```

With framework it's better to use `ActiveField` as an abstraction for displaying form inputs.

Customize it according to your models and that's it.

Comment: i cant use the normal form methodlike this " <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>" because the form gives me Undefined "variable: model"